# Parsing Google Speech API v2 Result in C#

Tags: c#, api, voice-recognition

I have the following code to send a FLAC file to google.

```
 FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead("G:\\hell.flac");
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            memoryStream.SetLength(fileStream.Length);
            fileStream.Read(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
            byte[] BA_AudioFile = memoryStream.GetBuffer();
            HttpWebRequest _HWR_SpeechToText = null;
            _HWR_SpeechToText =  (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?output=json&lang=en-us&key="+key);
            _HWR_SpeechToText.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            _HWR_SpeechToText.Method = "POST";
            _HWR_SpeechToText.ContentType = "audio/x-flac; rate=44100";
            _HWR_SpeechToText.ContentLength = BA_AudioFile.Length;
            Stream stream = _HWR_SpeechToText.GetRequestStream();
            stream.Write(BA_AudioFile, 0, BA_AudioFile.Length);
            stream.Close();
            String text = "";
            HttpWebResponse HWR_Response = (HttpWebResponse)_HWR_SpeechToText.GetResponse();

                StreamReader SR_Response = new StreamReader(HWR_Response.GetResponseStream());
                Console.WriteLine(SR_Response.ReadToEnd());
```

The output comes out to be.....

```
{"result":[]}
{"result":[{"alternative":[{"transcript":"good morning google good morning google","confidence":0.81179827},{"transcript":"goodmorning google good morning google"}],"final":true}],"result_index":0}
```

How Do I parse this and get the correct text. ??
Please Help

Comment: You're looking for a JSON parser.

Comment: Yes. I am looking for a Parser.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+json+parser

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Json.Net` to parse the result, just keep in mind that **in Google Speech API, each line is a valid json not the entire response, hence we should split the results** first.

```
        //Speech API response here
        var result =
            "{\"result\":[]}\n{\"result\":[{\"alternative\":[{\"transcript\":\"good morning Google how are you feeling today\",\"confidence\":0.93832707},{\"transcript\":\"goodmorning Google how are you feeling today\"},{\"transcript\":\"Good Morning Google how are you feeling today\"},{\"transcript\":\"good mornin Google how are you feeling today\"},{\"transcript\":\"good mourning Google how are you feeling today\"}],\"final\":true}],\"result_index\":0}\n";

        var jsons = result.Split('\n');

        foreach (var j in jsons)
        {
            dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(j);
            if (jsonObject == null || jsonObject.result.Count <= 0) continue;

            var text = jsonObject.result[0].alternative[0].transcript;
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
```

Or we can do it in a more static manner:

```
    public class SpeechAlternative
    {
        public string Transcript { get; set; }
        public double Confidence { get; set; }
    }

    public class SpeechResult
    {
        public SpeechAlternative[] Alternative { get; set; }
        public bool Final { get; set; }
    }

    public class SpeechResponse
    {
        public SpeechResult[] Result { get; set; }
        public int Result_Index { get; set; }
    }
```

The parsing part is not really different:

```
  var result =
                    "{\"result\":[]}\n{\"result\":[{\"alternative\":[{\"transcript\":\"good morning Google how are you feeling today\",\"confidence\":0.93832707},{\"transcript\":\"goodmorning Google how are you feeling today\"},{\"transcript\":\"Good Morning Google how are you feeling today\"},{\"transcript\":\"good mornin Google how are you feeling today\"},{\"transcript\":\"good mourning Google how are you feeling today\"}],\"final\":true}],\"result_index\":0}\n";

                var jsons = result.Split('\n');


                foreach (var j in jsons)
                {
                    var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SpeechResponse>(j);
                    if (jsonObject == null || jsonObject.Result.Length <= 0) continue;

                    var text = jsonObject.Result[0].Alternative[0].Transcript;
                    Console.WriteLine(text);
                }
```

Comment: Thanks You Sir. It worked Thanks a lot. Actually earlier JSON.net was being installed using Nuget. Then I downloaded the DLL and now It works like a charm. Thanx a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse your JSON. Example code, taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197957%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = 
    new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(User));
User user = (User)serializer.ReadObject(responseStream);

bool isMember = user.IsMember;
string name = user.Name;
int age = user.Age;
```